# Meanjs How to link one query to a different controller

Tags: angularjs, model, mean-stack, meanjs

I have one crud-module called article and anther one called Devices. I would like the data from article crud-module to be also in Device article. Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?

```
devicesApp.controller('DevicesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Devices','$modal', '$log',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Devices, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.devices = Devices.query();
```

And here is my articles query

```
$scope.articles = Articles.query();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (and shouldn't) communicate with controllers like this.
In order for this code to work, Articles and Devices need to be factories or services.

```
devicesApp.factory('Articles', function(){
  return {
    query: function(){
      return {/*Your data here*/};
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: Your next best option is to communicate between controllers via events.

Comment: Article and Device are two crud-modules and so i would use factories to call articles query?

Comment: My current possible/not working solution is under the device list view page i added articles controller but it seems it didn't call anything

Comment: Did you make them or is there documentation for them somewhere?
If they're already factories/services, then you should have an instance of them in your controller (you weren't clear about what kind of difficulties you're having with query()).
Can you show us what the query() function looks like?

Comment: If these are querying a server somewhere, these are likely to be asynchronous calls, but your code is expecting a synchronous response.
Hopefully, query() returns a promise. If so, then your code would be something like this:
Devices.query().then(function(data){/*do something with the data*/});

Comment: Thanks Alot man! I looking into the service and got it to work